# What should i do to create Detail object the same time as master object

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

//my apex page

I need to create Estimates__c object and Estimates_line__c object the same time.And my Estimate_line__c object is a detail class of master-detail relationship.(master-Estimates__c,detail Estimate_line__c).

```
<apex:page standardController="Estimates__c" extensions="EstimateController" id="page">
<apex:form id="MyForm">

    <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock" title="Page created by Me">
        <apex:repeat value="{!listOfSections}" var="section"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pageBlockSection1">
            <apex:inputField id="Project_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Project__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Customer_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Customer__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Contact_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Contacts_Person__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Estimate_status_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Status__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Note_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Notes__c}"/>
            <apex:commandButton id="New_row_add_button" value="Add new row" action="{!addSection}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:repeat>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons id="Section1_buttons_block">
            <apex:commandButton id="Save_data" value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                    <b><a href="#" onClick="clearValue()" > Clear </a> </b>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pageBlockSection1" showHeader="true" title="Section1">
            <apex:inputField id="Project_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Project__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Customer_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Customer__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Contact_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Contacts_Person__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Estimate_status_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Status__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Note_input_field" value="{!Estimates__c.Notes__c}"/>
            <apex:commandButton id="New_row_add_button" value="Add new row" action="{!addSection}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pageBlockSection2" showHeader="true" title="section2">
            <apex:inputField id="Quantity_from_estimates_line" value="{!line.Quantity__c}" label="Quantit"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Unit_price_input_field" value="{!line.Unit_price__c}" label="Unit_price"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Description_input_field" value="{!line.Description__c}" label="Description"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="section2_button_block" >
                <apex:commandButton id="Save_estimate_line_item" value="Save estimate line item" action="{!addLineItem}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

    <script>
    function clearValue()
    {
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:MyForm:pageBlock:pageBlockSection1:Project_input_field}').value = '';
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:MyForm:pageBlock:pageBlockSection1:Customer_input_field}').value = '';
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:MyForm:pageBlock:pageBlockSection1:Contacts_Person__c}').value = '';
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:MyForm:pageBlock:pageBlockSection1:Status__c}').value = '';
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:MyForm:pageBlock:pageBlockSection1:Notes__c}').value = '';
    return false;
    }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

//my controller code

```
public with sharing class EstimateController {
    public List<String>listOfSections {get;set;}
    public Estimates__c estimate {get;set;}
    public Estimate_lines__c line {get;set;} 
    public List<Estimate_lines__c> line1 {get;set;} 

    public EstimateController(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
        line = new Estimate_lines__c();
        listOfSections = new List<String> ();
        line1 = (List<Estimate_lines__c>)[select Name,Quantity__c,Unit_price__c,Description__c from Estimate_lines__c];
    }
    public PageReference addSection(){
        listOfSections.add('asdasd');
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference addLineItem(){
        Integer size = line1.size();
        line1.add(line);
        upsert line1;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following all your code, but if you are inserting the standard controller object and also want to insert a child object of that you can use code that looks like this:

```
private ApexPages.StandardController sc;

public EstimateController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    this.sc = sc;
    ...
}

public PageReference save() {
    // Insert parent first so an ID is allocated and available
    Estimates__c estimates = (Estimates__c) sc.getRecord();
    upsert estimates;
    // Set reference to parent on child and insert child
    line.Estimates__c = estimates.Id;
    upsert lines;
    // Probably want to go to a different page here; null will leave you on the same page
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,i didnt try it yet.But my friend was specaking something the same.Il try it and rep to you.